# Task vs Continuation scheduling

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task, taskscheduler

Suppose I have many CPU intensive tasks that get dumped on the default scheduler (all run at once, e.g via `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` with default scheduler).  Each task has a Continuation.  The scheduler will start a few of the tasks and put them in a running state.  When those Tasks finish the scheduler then has a mix of original tasks and continuation tasks in its queue to schedule and has to choose between them.  How does it prioritise the continuations vs running more of the org Tasks.  Specifically if a Task has completed and it has a continuation does that continuation get priority in the scheduler over other tasks that are already queued.

For example suppose the sheduler runs 2 (T1 & T2) of the many (T1...Tn) queued tasks.  When one of those is complete will the scheduler necessarily run the continuation C1 or might it decide to start T3?  Is it in anyway deterministic which it will choose?  Is it possible that the scheduler will choose to run more Tasks and that therefor the can be considerable delay between the end of T1 and the start of its continuation C1?

Update: Ive run some example code and added an answer - **but I would still like to hear if this observed behaviour is guaranteed?**

Comment: Which scheduler? You are aware you can implement your own? You mean the default scheduler?

Comment: @TomTom Question clarified.

Comment: It seems the height of folly to count on *any* ordering of tasks by the scheduler, except ordering that's enforced by you through continuations and ordered `await`s. I'm tempted to categorically state *no, this is not guaranteed, because it would put undue burden on the implementation to be shackled to this for all time*, but since I'm not a Microsoft employee, I don't feel comfortable doing so. In general, though: in a parallel word, if you're not synchronizing things, then things aren't synchronized, except by happenstance.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried it with a sample:

```
var continuations = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    int counter = i;
    var continuation = Task.Run(() => {
        Console.WriteLine($"T{counter}: Start.");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine($"T{counter}: Complete.");
    }).ContinueWith(t => {
        Console.WriteLine($"C{counter}: Start.");
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Console.WriteLine($"C{counter}: Complete.");
    });
    continuations.Add(continuation);
}
Task.WaitAll(continuations.ToArray());
```

Which outputs the following - **implying that the scheduler does prioritise the continuation over starting a new tasks (but is this guaranteed?)** :

```
T1: Start.
T2: Start.
T3: Start.
T0: Start.
T1: Complete.
T2: Complete.
T3: Complete.
C1: Start.
C3: Start.
T0: Complete.
C0: Start.
C2: Start.
C1: Complete.
T4: Start.
C3: Complete.
T5: Start.
C0: Complete.
T6: Start.
C2: Complete.
T7: Start.
T4: Complete.
C4: Start.
T5: Complete.
C5: Start.
T6: Complete.
C6: Start.
T7: Complete.
C7: Start.
C4: Complete.
C5: Complete.
T9: Start.
T8: Start.
C7: Complete.
T10: Start.
C6: Complete.
T11: Start.
T8: Complete.
C8: Start.
T9: Complete.
C9: Start.
T11: Complete.
C11: Start.
T10: Complete.
C10: Start.
C9: Complete.
C8: Complete.
T13: Start.
T12: Start.
C11: Complete.
T14: Start.
C10: Complete.
```

A variation. Here there is additional execution on the calling thread between starting the Task and registering the Continuation.

```
var continuations = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    int counter = i;
    var task = Task.Run(() => {
        Console.WriteLine($"T{counter}: Start.");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine($"T{counter}: Complete.");
    });
    Thread.Sleep(100); // Do some stuff before registering continuation.
    var continuation = task.ContinueWith(t => {
    Console.WriteLine($"C{counter}: Start.");
        Thread.Sleep(150);
        Console.WriteLine($"C{counter}: Complete.");
    });
    continuations.Add(continuation);
}
Task.WaitAll(continuations.ToArray());
```

Result is the same as above case i.e Continuation for task N is given priority of other queued tasks.

```
T0: Start.
T1: Start.
T2: Start.
T3: Start.
T0: Complete.
C0: Start.
T1: Complete.
C1: Start.
C0: Complete.
T4: Start.
T2: Complete.
C2: Start.
C1: Complete.
T5: Start.
T3: Complete.
C3: Start.
C2: Complete.
T6: Start.
C3: Complete.
T7: Start.
T4: Complete.
C4: Start.
T5: Complete.
C5: Start.
C4: Complete.
T8: Start.
T6: Complete.
C6: Start.
C5: Complete.
T9: Start.
T7: Complete.
C7: Start.
C6: Complete.
T10: Start.
C7: Complete.
T11: Start.
T8: Complete.
C8: Start.
T9: Complete.
C9: Start.
C8: Complete.
T12: Start.
T10: Complete.
C10: Start.
C9: Complete.
T13: Start.
T11: Complete.
C11: Start.
T14: Start.
C10: Complete.
T15: Start.
C11: Complete.
T16: Start.
T12: Complete.
C12: Start.
T13: Complete.
C13: Start.
T14: Complete.
C14: Start.
C12: Complete.
T17: Start.
T15: Complete.
C15: Start.......
```

Another variation.  Here ALL tasks are queued on scheuler first (and and can be scheduled to run) BEFORE registering the continuations.

```
const int taskCount = 20;
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++) {
    int counter = i;
    var task = Task.Run(() => {
        Console.WriteLine($"T{counter}: Start.");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine($"T{counter}: Complete.");
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}
Thread.Sleep(400);
var continuations = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++) {
    int counter = i;
    var continuation = tasks[i].ContinueWith(t => {
        Console.WriteLine($"C{counter}: Start.");
        Thread.Sleep(150);
        Console.WriteLine($"C{counter}: Complete.");
    });
    continuations.Add(continuation);
}
Task.WaitAll(continuations.ToArray());
```

Result is as before - continuations get priority.

```
T0: Start.
T2: Start.
T3: Start.
T1: Start.
T1: Complete.
T3: Complete.
T0: Complete.
T2: Complete.
C2: Start.
C0: Start.
C3: Start.
C1: Start.
C2: Complete.
C1: Complete.
C0: Complete.
C3: Complete.
T7: Start.
T4: Start.
T6: Start.
T5: Start.
T6: Complete.
T5: Complete.
T7: Complete.
T4: Complete.
C6: Start.
C5: Start.
C7: Start.
C4: Start.
C7: Complete.
T8: Start.
C5: Complete.
T9: Start.
C6: Complete.
T10: Start.
C4: Complete.
T11: Start.
T8: Complete.
C8: Start.
T10: Complete.
C10: Start.
T9: Complete.
C9: Start.
T11: Complete.
C11: Start.
C8: Complete.
T12: Start.
C9: Complete.
T13: Start.
C10: Complete.
T14: Start.
C11: Complete.
T15: Start.
T14: Complete.
T12: Complete.
C12: Start.
T13: Complete.
C13: Start.
C14: Start.
T15: Complete.
C15: Start.
T16: Start.
C12: Complete.
C13: Complete.
T18: Start.
T17: Start.
C14: Complete.
T19: Start.
C15: Complete.
T16: Complete.
C16: Start.
T18: Complete.
C18: Start.
T17: Complete.
T19: Complete.
C19: Start.
C16: Complete.
C17: Start.
C18: Complete.
C19: Complete.
C17: Complete.
```